# SQL Best way to store the day and week or weekend day (time and attendance)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a sql table where Im going to store every employee time record (IN and OUT).

The table schema is:

[image]

So, in order to make easier the calculation for working hours, vacations, holidays, etc.. I would like also to include into the same table a new field:

- `isweekday`: that will let me know if the day is weekday or not (will be helpful for future calculation)

But also want to know the day (monday, tuesday, etc.) I was thinking on a **tinyint** datatype from 1 to 7 where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday.

Any advice or recomendation? In C# or SQL does Monday equals to first day of week?

Comment: SQL Server has the `datepart()` function which already returns the day of the week.  Including in the table is unnecessary redundancy.  The holiday flag, on the other hand, is a good idea.

Comment: So you think its unecessary to create a "day" tinyint field for storing just the day. I was thinking on this in order to avoid doing more math on server side. But i think you are right.

Comment: . . I wouldn't say never, just 9+9% percent of the time.  Adding 7 bit flags adds at most one byte to the size of each record.  If the server had a very, very heavy CPU load, then perhaps not calling a built-in function and reading the value would have a small incremental performance benefit.

Comment: totally agree :), do you want to create the answer? and I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `isholiday` flag is quite useful.  The alternative is to look up holidays in a table, but having the data directly in the record is easy.  And, because you already have bit flags, one more flag will probably not make the field any larger.

Identifying the day of week or weekends is less useful.  SQL Server already provides functions to do this, notably `datepart()` and `datename()`.

There are some circumstances where these can be difficult to use.  For instance, if you have to write code that runs on any system, regardless of language and any local preferences for when the week starts, then storing the information in the record could be useful.  That is, `datepart()` and `datename()` are not deterministic, because they depend on system parameters.  However, for the majority of applications that are written for one culture, this is not much of an issue.

Also, under some circumstances that I could imagine, the overhead to call a system function might be larger than the time to read a value from a record.  In a heavily CPU constrained environment, you might want to store the flags.  However, I suspect that there would be other more important optimizations.